# Making animations not smooth while using Record button

Tags: unity, animation

In my 2D sidescroller game, I want to separate the animations for the head and the body of my character.

While idling, my charcter's body bounces slightly up and down (kind of a breathing motion). Thus, the head should keep up.
However, when I press `Record` and make adjustments for the head, the head moves up and down smoothly instead of following the body frame by frame.

How can I remove the smooth transitions from one position to the other?

Here is a screenshot from Unity demonstrating the hierarchy and the animation keyframes.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us how your character's parts are constructed in the hierarchy window, and how your keyframes look in the animation timeline?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the platform of GameDev, so I am not able to comment, but you will not be able to control or record it the way you want. Unity makes smooth animations with the record button. So you can probably make a sprite sheet of some sorts and use that instead, but the way you want it to work is quite impossible with the record button. Also, I think you should use [Anima2d](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-anima2d-79840) instead of the record button because the record button is too limited.

Comment: There is a tutrial on how to use anima2d by Sergio's Tech. [Here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG4AeOriIco)

Comment: can someone please upvote my answer. I would really appreciate it.